# How to format a system of differential equations in latex?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, amsmath, cases

Which is the best way of formatting system of differential equations ? Is there a special package maybe ?
I'm actually using the environment

```
\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}
```

But I'am having trouble to align all the boundary condition to the right ? Do you have any suggestion here a sample of the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\chi \bigg[ C_{m} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + I_{ion}\big( v,\mathbf{w},\mathbf{c} \big) \bigg]  =  \div \big( \mathbf{D_{M}} \div v \big) + I_{app} \qquad & \Omega_{0}^{s} \times \big(0,T\big]\\[20pt] 

\displaystyle
\frac{\partial \mathbf{w}}{\partial t}  = \mathbf{R}(v,\mathbf{w},\mathbf{c} \big)  \qquad & \Omega_{0}^{s} \times \big(0,T\big]  \\[20pt] 

\displaystyle 
\frac{\partial \mathbf{w} }{ \partial t} = \mathbf{S} \big(v,\mathbf{w},\mathbf{c} \big) \qquad & \Omega_{0}^{s} \times \big(0,T\big] \\[20pt]

\displaystyle
\big( \mathbf{D_M} \nabla v ) \cdot  \mathbf{N_S} = 0 \qquad & \partial \Omega_{0}^{s} \times \big(0,T\big] \\[20pt]

\displaystyle
 v = v_{0} \quad \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{w_{0}} \quad  \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{c_{0}} &  \partial  \Omega_{0}^{s}  \times \{ 0 \}  \\[20pt]
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In the picture the boundary condition are aligned on the left side instead I would like to align them on the right ( as the red line )

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find some of the environments in `mathtools` useful for this.  In particular, `dcases` is like cases, but each line is in display mode, and `spreadlines` changes the line spacing of aligned environments.  I also used `aligned`, from `amsmath`, to add more alignment points.

I also took the liberty of defining a `\vectorsym` macro, for readability and so you can change the formatting of all your vectors in one place.

This MWE uses LuaLaTeX, but the body should work fine with your own preamble (You can use `isomath` for `\vectorsym` in PDFTeX, should you need to.)

i also declared some of your paired delimiters with a `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command, which takes an optional size argument.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\symbfit{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\closedopen{\lbrack}{\rparen}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadlines}{2ex}
\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
\begin{aligned}
\chi \bigg[ C_{m} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + I_{ion}\big( v,\vectorsym{w},\vectorsym{c} \big) \bigg]  &= 
  \nabla \big( \vectorsym{D_{M}} \nabla v \big) + I_{app} \qquad  &\Omega_{0}^{s} &\times \closedopen[\big]{0,T} \\
\frac{\partial \vectorsym{w}}{\partial t}  &=
  \vectorsym{R}(v,\vectorsym{w},\vectorsym{c} \big)  \qquad  &\Omega_{0}^{s} &\times \closedopen[\big]{0,T}  \\
\frac{\partial \vectorsym{w} }{ \partial t} &=
  \vectorsym{S} \big(v,\vectorsym{w},\vectorsym{c} \big) \qquad  &\Omega_{0}^{s} &\times \closedopen[\big]{0,T} \\
\big( \vectorsym{D_M} \nabla v ) \cdot  \vectorsym{N_S} &=
  0 \qquad &\partial \Omega_{0}^{s} &\times \closedopen[\big]{0,T} \\
 v = v_{0} \quad \vectorsym{w} = \vectorsym{w_{0}} \quad  \vectorsym{c} &=
  \vectorsym{c_{0}} &\partial  \Omega_{0}^{s}  &\times \{ 0 \} 
\end{aligned}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{spreadlines}

\end{document}
```

[image: mathtools sample]

Also, `physics` (which I’m not too familiar with) seems to redefine `\div` to mean `\nabla\cdot`, but in standard LaTeX, that means ÷.  I’m editing now because that tripped me up, and I’d recommend you not use ambiguous code like this.

Comment: There's no need to use `dcases` if you use `aligned` inside `cases` (but I'd not recommend aligning the unrelated equals signs), because `aligned` forces display style by itself.

Comment: Yes this seems good , but there is also the possibility to label each equations ?

Comment: @RIXS One way to do this would be to change `\begin{equation}` to `\begin{equation*}` and add a `\tag` at te end of each sub-equation, e.g. (1a), (1b). Auto-numbering those would be more work.

Answer (score 8):

You need nothing really special. I'd avoid all those `20pt` that are too much.

Just to avoid issuing `\displaystyle` each time, I used `dcases` from `mathtools`.

The `physics` package redefines `\div` (which is not a good thing); instead of loading it just for that, use a simple definition of `\Div`.

In order to simplify input, I defined a `\pder` command and also a `\vect` command for vectors to make the input more semantic.

The two subscripts in the first equation should be upright, because they're words rather than symbols.

The lines are equally spaced with the trick of inserting a phantom partial derivative in the last two rows (the second one smashed at the bottom). The `\mystrut` command is temporary, just for that `equation` environment.

Note that `\bigg` should instead be either `\biggl` or `\biggr` (left and right delimiters). I removed all `\big` (that should be `\bigl` or `\bigr`), because they don't seem really necessary.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{physics} % I'd recommend avoiding it

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}} % or use diffcoeff
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\Div}{\bm{\nabla}\cdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\vphantom{\pder{}{}}}
\begin{dcases}
\chi \biggl( C_{m} \pder{v}{t} + I_{\mathrm{ion}}(v,\vect{w},\vect{c}) \biggr) =
  \Div (\vect{D_{M}} \Div v) + I_{\mathrm{app}}
& \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
\pder{\vect{w}}{t} = \vect{R}(v,\vect{w},\vect{c})
& \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
\pder{\vect{w}}{t} = \vect{S} (v,\vect{w},\vect{c} )
& \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
\mystrut
(\vect{D_M} \Div v ) \cdot \vect{N_S} = 0
& \partial\Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
\smash[b]{\mystrut}
v = v_{0} \quad \vect{w} = \vect{w_{0}} \quad  \vect{c} = \vect{c_{0}}
& \partial\Omega_{0}^{s}  \times \{ 0 \}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want right aligned boundary conditions, you can use `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{physics} % I'd recommend avoiding it

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}} % or use diffcoeff
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\Div}{\bm{\nabla}\cdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\vphantom{\pder{}{}}}
\left\lbrace
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\chi \biggl( C_{m} \pder{v}{t} + I_{\mathrm{ion}}(v,\vect{w},\vect{c}) \biggr) =
  \Div (\vect{D_{M}} \Div v) + I_{\mathrm{app}}
&\quad \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
&\pder{\vect{w}}{t} = \vect{R}(v,\vect{w},\vect{c})
&\quad \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
&\pder{\vect{w}}{t} = \vect{S} (v,\vect{w},\vect{c} )
&\quad \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
&\mystrut
(\vect{D_M} \Div v ) \cdot \vect{N_S} = 0
&\quad \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]
\\[1ex]
&\smash[b]{\mystrut}
v = v_{0} \quad \vect{w} = \vect{w_{0}} \quad  \vect{c} = \vect{c_{0}}
&\quad \Omega_{0}^{s}  \times \{ 0 \}
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `alignedat` makes pairs of right-left aligned columns. So the equations are in the “left aligned part” of the first pair, whereas the boundary conditions are in the “right aligned part” of the second pair.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No need to employ a `cases` environment. I suggest you employ an `alignedat` environment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignedat' environment
\usepackage{amssymb,physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\addtolength{\jot}{5pt}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\chi \smash[b]{ \Bigl[ C_{m} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} 
               + I_{\mathrm{ion}}( v,\mathbf{w},\mathbf{c}) \Bigr] }  
  =  \div ( \mathbf{D}_{\mathrm{M}} \div v ) + I_{\mathrm{app}} 
  &\qquad&& \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]\\
\frac{\partial \mathbf{w}}{\partial t}  
  = \mathbf{R}(v,\mathbf{w},\mathbf{c} ) 
  &&&\Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T]  \\ 
\frac{\partial \mathbf{w} }{ \partial t} 
  = \mathbf{S} (v,\mathbf{w},\mathbf{c} )  
  &&& \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T] \\
( \mathbf{D}_{\mathrm{M}} \nabla v ) \cdot  \mathbf{N_S} = 0 
  &&& \partial \Omega_{0}^{s} \times (0,T] \\
v = v_{0} \quad \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{w}_{0} \quad \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{c}_{0} 
  &&&  \partial  \Omega_{0}^{s}  \times \{ 0 \}  
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Right alignment? Why?

Comment: @egreg - The OP wrote that he/she wanted to "align all the boundary condition[s] to the right". I interpreted that as "right alignment". Is my interpretation faulty?

Comment: The boundary conditions are those on the right side (second column), as far as I can tell.

Comment: @egreg - yeah, in that case my interpretation was definitely faulty...

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few tips and tricks before my answer

---

- While your example is fairly minimal, I would still recommend removing packages that are not necessary for compilation. Examples: `physics`,`babel`.
- I would recommend steering clear of the package `physics`. It is somewhat *infamous* as a behemoth. It attempts to do too much, and does none of them particularly well. There are other smaller packages that produces better results.
- I recommend using the [`diffcoeff`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/diffcoeff/diffcoeff.pdf) package as seen below.
- I also recommend using `vec` over `mathbf`, as it is much more explicit
  in the code what you mean. Using `vec` you know you are dealing with vectors when reading the code. In addition it is also much easier to change the notation to using arrows for instance.
- To my knowledge there does not exists any packages for producing system of differential equations, but an adequate output can be produced using `alignedat`. The package `systeme` can also be used, which I guess the other answer might use.
- I would strongly recommend you formating your code better. Using indents, and aligning the `&` and `=`'s in your code will make it much more readable when you come back to it after a while.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{dcases}
    {\begin{alignedat}{3}
     & \chi\biggl[C_m \diffp vt +I_{ion}(v,\vec{w},\vec{c})\biggr]
     = \div (\vec{D_M}\div v)+I_{app}  \qquad
     & \Omega_0^s &\times (0,T]\\
     & \diffp {\vec{w}}t
     = \vec{R}(v,\vec{w},\vec{c}) 
     & \Omega_0^s & \times (0,T]\\
     & \diffp {\vec{w}}t
     = \vec{S}(v,\vec{w},\vec{c}) 
     & \Omega_0^s & \times (0,T]\\
     &(\vec{D_M}\nabla u) \cdot \vec{N}_S = 0 
     & \partial \Omega_0^s & \times (0,T]\\
     & v = v_0 \quad \vec{w}=\vec{w_0} \quad \vec{c}=\vec{c_0}
     & \partial \Omega_0^s & \times \{0\}
    \end{alignedat}}
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```